# Arithmetic comparison operator using if inside a for loop in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to run the below logic in a bash script

```
  for i in {1..30}:
  do
  printf $i 
  if (( $i!=30 )); then
    printf ","
  fi
  done
```

After hours of google searching, I found that in an if condition, square brackets `[ ]` are used for string comparisons and circular brackets are used for arithmetic operations `(( ))`. I also found that `-ne` is used for string and `!=` has to be used for arithmetic operations.

Inspite of my best efforts, I am unable to successfully run this simple logic where I need to run the loop 30 times and print the output with commas but skip the comma in last iteration.

Comment: You mean like this? `for i in {1..30};   do   printf $i ;   if [ "$i" != "30" ]; then     printf ",";   fi;   done`

Comment: `-ne` etc are *not* used for string comparisons. Inside `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`, you use `-eq`, `-ne`, etc for numeric comparisons and `=` (note: just one equal sign, although bash allows two), `!=`, etc for string comparisons. In arithmetic contexts like `(( ))`, you use `==` (note: double-equal), `!=`, etc for numeric comparisons, `=` for assignment, and there are no string operators. In other words: the operators change *completely* depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the colon `:` after the curly braces in the first line:

```
for i in {1..30}
do
  printf $i 
  if (( $i!=30 )); then
    printf ","
  fi
done
```

This prints what you want:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

Comment: Thanks. some of the examples I saw used colon for a for loop so I used it.

Comment: Were you looking at Python examples? I can't imagine why any shell examples would use a colon. (Or did you really see a semicolon (`;`)? One would be required if `do` were on the same line as `for`, but would be optional otherwise.)